# .net mvc core json data is null at controller after post

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I am new in .net mvc core and creating a sample application for inserting a row in database. I am able to display data but inserting data is creating a problem. `customer.Name` is null at line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", customer.Name)`. Please advice

```
 public JsonResult InsertCustomer(CustomerModel customer)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Customers VALUES(@Name, @Country)";
        query += "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
        //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        string constr = _configuration.GetConnectionString("PagerefineDB");
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", customer.Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", customer.Country);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                customer.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return Json(customer);
    }
```

```html
 //Add event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
            var txtName = $("#txtName");
            var txtCountry = $("#txtCountry");
           
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/InsertCustomer",
                data: '{name: "' + txtName.val() + '", country: "' + txtCountry.val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var row = $("#tblCustomers tr:last-child");
                    if ($("#tblCustomers tr:last-child span").eq(0).html() != "&nbsp;") {
                        row = row.clone();
                    }
                    AppendRow(row, r.CustomerId, r.Name, r.Country);
                    txtName.val("");
                    txtCountry.val("");
                }
            });
        });
```

I guess this is something because of difference between .net and .net core. 
[image]

Comment: Did you print and checked customer object in `InsertCustomer(...` it might be coming as null or its property `name` might be null.

Comment: customer is not null but name and country are null... am I missing something

Comment: Now you got the point `name` is null that is why you are getting error. Now you check why it is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> customer.Name is null at line cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", customer.Name).

Based on your JavaScript code, we can find that you pass data through the request body, not formdata. You can try to apply [the `[FromBody]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-attribute) to action parameter, like below.

```
public JsonResult InsertCustomer([FromBody]CustomerModel customer)
{
   //...
```

Test Result

[image]

Update1:

Try to wrap keys `name` and `country` with `""`, like below.

```
data:  '{"name": "' + txtName.val() + '", "country": "' + txtCountry.val() + '" }',
```

Update2:

*Posting data via form data*

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("name", "test1");
form.append("country", "country1");

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/InsertCustomer',
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    datatype: 'json',
    success:
    //....
```

*Controller action*

```
public JsonResult InsertCustomer(CustomerModel customer)
{
    //...
```

Comment: This is not working when I am using FromBody then even customer is null

Comment: I am using this example https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Database-Connection-without-using-Entity-Framework.aspx in .net core

Comment: Hi @Anurag, you can wrap keys `name` and `country` with `""` as I did.

Comment: Did the same but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks its working. Can you please tell me how can i do it via formdata and what is the difference formdata and frombody

Comment: `what is the difference formdata and frombody` You can check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sources